# JSON stringify() and OR operator

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I found this [sample in an AngularJS book](https://github.com/angular-app/Samples/blob/master/1820EN_03_Code/08%20-%20custom%20resource/customResource.js#L27).

How can line 27 be correct?

```
params:angular.extend({q:JSON.stringify({} || params)}, defaultParams)
```

The `JSON.stringify({} || params)` always returns `{}` but it should use the defined `params` object.

Comment: IMO the author meant to wrote: `JSON.stringify(params || {})`. you're welcome to create a PR.

Comment: I agree, it should be `JSON.stringify(params || {})`. Maybe a simple mistake?

Comment: I am sure the author will be happy to hear from you.

Comment: I gave the author my issue on github, thanks y'all.